# compile my resx files from outside my visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, embedded-resource, resx

i have a few resource files (.resx) in a dll.

this dll is referenced from my website, and compiling creates a 'admin.UserControlResource.dll' dll in my \bin\language folder from my 'UserControlResource.de.resx'

now i have some new resource files (the .resx text file), and i want to compile them into new dll's, outside my project, so i will able to just copy those dll's to my production server.

i tried resgen.exe, but that won't allow me to specify the .dll extension for the generated file.

i tried another extension and rename it to .dll, but that didn't work.

this is what i tried:

```
resgen UserControlResource.de.resx
     al.exe /t:lib /culture:de /embed:"UserControlResource.de.resources" /out:"Dwight.UserControl.resources.dll"
```

i've seen (in examples) al.exe been executed with and without /t:lib, but both don't work.

what do i mean with 'dont work'?

resgen creates a .resources file

al.exe creates a dll and shows no warnings

but when i copy the dll to the server the default english resources are used, and not the german (de) ones.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to create satellite assemblies and deploy those satellite assemblies. Theres a good explanation of the process and what you need to consider on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Hope that helps :)

Comment: i used resgen to create a .resources file from the .resx file, and al.exe to create a resource dll from the .resources file, but no luck

Comment: Hi Michel, can you explain what happened, I am not sure what you mean by "no luck". Did resgen do what you expected, what did al.exe produce for example.

Comment: good point, 'no luck' is not so meaningfull.... i'll edit the question and show what i did.

Comment: I wonder does your original User Control know that its localized which is one possible explanation - set Localizable=true and you also have to add your langauges to the control,for example, German(de).  I'm also wondering if this is a desktop application or a web application/page. http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/tag/localization/ does a very good step by step approach for an asp.net page, same should apply to a WebUserControl.

Answer (score 1):

I found a sequence of resgen.exe and al.exe commands that worked for me:

Resgen.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ResGen.exe" Strings.resx
```

Output:

```
Read in 10 resources from "Strings.resx"
Writing resource file...  Done.
```

Al.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\al.exe" /t:lib /embed:Strings.resources /culture:en /out:Strings.dll
```

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Assembly Linker Version 12.0.20806.33440
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

The output of this is a dll that can be included into the released version without using Visual Studio.

Comment: This works, but I had to add another argument in the first command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ResGen.exe" Strings.resx YOURAPPLICATIONNAME.Properties.Resources.en.resources

Otherwise I can't reliably replace the dll in the Release version.